# Saving unique data via php form submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple PHP script, which saves the submitted data from the form inside a `.txt` file.

Problem is with duplicate entries (`For example` When someone submits the form multiple times with the same name and email), which I have to cleanup additionally.

`PHP Script` below:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $option = $_POST['option'];
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname_field = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
    $terms = $_POST['terms'];
    $file = "collect.txt";

    $data = "$name_field; $lastname_field; $email_field; $option; $terms;\n";
    $fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");
    fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

    fclose($fp); 
    header ('index.php');

}
```

Is there a way to filter out or to prevent writing the data inside `.txt` if the email was already submitted?

Comment: Either avoid duplicate entries by reading the file to check whether the data you're about to append to it are already there, or accept duplicate entries and filter them when  you have to actually *use* the stored data.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a CSV formatted file ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just search for the email before inserting it into the text file.

```
$data = "$name_field; $lastname_field; $email_field; $option; $terms;\n";
$fp = fopen($file, "r+") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");

$contents = fread($fp, filesize($file));

if (strpos($contents, $email_field) === false) {
    fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!");
}
else {
    die('Email exists');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique ID to a computer, for instance via a cookie/session. Use this ID to store the file on your computer. Now if a user resubmits the form, for instance because they made a correction, overwrite the old file.

Comment: I think this is the most proper way to do this.

Comment: What if the user clears their cookies? They would be able to submit the form again.

Comment: You're right, but that's a rare problem. If you check the email address the user could use multiple email addresses, and you have the same problem. It is unclear how far you're willing to take this, but you could prevent both.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a search through the file for info. To open the file, just use `file_get_contents()`.
However, this is one of the reason you shouldn't use files, but databases.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if file contents contain the email you need

```
$contents = fread($fp, filesize($file));
if(strpos($contents, "; $email_field;") === 0)
{
   // email already in file
}else
{
   // append data to file
}
```

you should use some more complex regexp to make sure the email is already in the file but its not submitted as a lastname for example

Answer (score 0):

```
$option = $_POST['option'];
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$lastname_field = $_POST['lastname'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$terms = $_POST['terms'];
$file = "collect.txt";

$data = "$name_field; $lastname_field; $email_field; $option; $terms;\n";
$fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");

$ok = true;

while (($line = fgets($fp)) !== false) {
    $arr = explode(";", $data);
    if($arr[2] === $email_field) {
       $ok = false;
    }
}

if($ok) {
   fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 
}

fclose($fp); 
header ('index.php');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful of your file structure... What if I type `My;wonderful;name;\n` in the input field of `name` ? Your data will be messed up...
As your data looks like a CSV formatted file, I think you should use related PHP functions to handle your file structure :

- [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php) : in order to read your CSV file
- [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fputcsv.php) : in order to build your CSV file, without having to take care of the data

You will then have something like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $option = $_POST['option'];
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname_field = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
    $terms = $_POST['terms'];
    $file = "collect.txt";

    $fpr = fopen($file, "r") or die("Couldn't open $file for reading!");

    while ($line = fgetcsv($fpr)) {
        if ($line[2] == $email_field) {
            // email already exists (give the user a message)
            fclose($fpr);
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
    fclose($fpr);

    $data = array(
        $name_field,
        $lastname_field,
        $email_field,
        $option,
        $terms
    );

    $fpw = fopen($file, "w") or die("Couldn't open $file for writing!");

    fputcsv($fpw, $data);

    fclose($fpw); 
    header('Location: index.php'); // note here your wrong header

}
```